# Facebook Javascript SDK automatically like a facebook page

Tags: sdk, facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-like

Is it possible to request permissions to allow your application like a facebook page on behalf of the user. Also could someone highlight the part of the API that is used to like the page, eg is there FB.LikePage etc?

Comment: Is it still not possible? Or facebook already implemented this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is just not possible using facebook's API, The reason is obvious, if they allow applications to like pages on behalf of the user, then its like welcoming all spammers to scam all facebook users and people won't have any idea what just happened as soon as they've allowed the application and its like liking something which is not of my interest!

I don't think facebook will allow something like this in future as well, if they allow, then they should be prepared to handle all spams/scams.

Answer (score 0):

From what i've used the Facebook API it is not possible and it doesn't make any sense to allow such a behaviour

Comment: Actually it would make sense - Facebook already allows you to prompt users for a variety of permissions - including posting to their wall as the user on their behalf, reading their inbox, complete list of friends, personal information etc - It would make sense to allow an application associated with a facebook page to request permission to like itself.  My guess is that Facebook hasn't / doesn't want to work out the logistics with this since technically a page and app are seperate entities.