# Using PHP in order to share a message at user's frind's wall

Tags: php, facebook, hyperlink, share, photos

I'm trying to share text and a picture at user's wall using only PHP, obviously at Facebbok, but can't do it. I have read that just changing /me/feed by /'id_user'/feed but I faild, I wondering if sb has code about this?? thank a lot

Comment: Why don't you use the share dialog or the share url?  This way you save some work, but if you really need to use the graph api remember that you must have asked the user for the publish_actions. You can read more about that permission here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look to the facebook API :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/
and :
http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/graph-api-iframe-base-facebook-application-development/

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to post to another user's wall when you only have an access token for your user you can't do that anymore since February 2013.

[Here's another question like yours that explains why.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764963/facebook-javascript-sdk-automatically-like-a-facebook-page)